# php mysqli SELECT doesnt return row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this code:

```
$check_user = "SELECT * FROM privateChats WHERE name = '$category'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$check_user);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if($row["user1"] == $login_session or $row["user2"] == $login_session){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM privateChat WHERE name = '$category' ORDER BY position DESC";
}
// it goes on
```

It gets stuck at `$result = mysqli_query($conn,$check_user);` it doesn't give an error either.
There is a table called `privateChats` and there is a record in it.

My connection code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "thewhateverclub";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "my_thewhateverclub";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error($conn)) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error($conn));
}
```

Comment: can you paste your connection part?

Comment: What do you mean with “it doesn't give an error”? Have you also tried `mysqli_query(...) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` ? Also, are sure that `$category` is set?

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code. Why not check that `user1` or `user2` = `login_session` then get the records you need? Also what does `gets stuck at` mean?

Comment: I have tried to get the error

Comment: And `$category` is set.

Comment: After using Rahul Dambare suggestion of displaying errors I found out what was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM privateChats WHERE name = '$category'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Data1 " . $row["column1"]. " - Data2: " . $row["column2"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Also add this line at the start of your php script.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

However, this doesn't make PHP to show parse errors - the only way to show those errors is to modify your php.ini with this line:

```
display_errors = on
```

Comment: This line `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` is doing the same thing `display_errors = on` but for duration of the current script. OP shouldn't edit php.ini, might output content on other live scripts (e.g. DB credentials could be exposed with that). Your PHP also has too many quotes `. " "<br>"`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check mysqli **Errors** by below way:-

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

//check connection error 
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
// check variable is set or not
$category = isset($category) ? $category : 'notSet';
$check_user = "SELECT * FROM privateChats WHERE name = '$category'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$check_user);

// Check for query errors
if(!$result){
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn));
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Hope it will help you :)